# android mediaplayer does not play video, only audio when rotating surfaceview

Tags: android, video, rotation, surfaceview

### Edit: My issue not solved yet!

Hello stackoverflow friends.
I wrote a video player which can play my recorded videos. But there was rotating 90 degree problem when showing. I used from mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(int degree) ,but I guess My video player ignores the composition matrix in video during palyback( according to `setOrientationHint` documentation),Because this method hasn’t any effect on rotation. Finally I decided directly in my video player editing `surfaceView` by rotating canvas matrix. But this way has this issue which cant show my video in surface view. Only I can hear voice without any showing! How can I resolve this issue? 
If there are other ways for rotating my video in `surfaceView` I want know about those ways. I searched a lot for rotating but I couldnt get any success.

This is most importants piece of my code.

```
public class VideoPlayerActivity extends Activity  implements 
SurfaceHolder.Callback 
{

      private SurfaceView mPreview;
        private SurfaceHolder holder;
         private MediaPlayer mPlayer;

        //-------------------------------------------    

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.video_player);
                        InitializeUI();
        }



         //------------------------------------------
         private void InitializeUI()
         {
                mPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
                holder = mPreview.getHolder();
                       holder.addCallback(this);
                       holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_NORMAL);
    }
         //------------------------------------------

private void playVideo(Integer Media) 
        {

            try {

     Canvas canvas=holder.lockCanvas();
    Matrix mat=canvas.getMatrix();
    mat.postRotate(90);
     canvas.setMatrix(mat);
                 holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

                mPlayer.reset();    
    mPlayer.setDataSource(ArrayManager.array_for_playing.get(SDcard.icurrentIndex).getPath());


                 mPlayer.setDisplay(holder);

                mPlayer.prepare();
                mPlayer.start();


            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                Log.e("video player", "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
  //------------------------------------------
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) 
        {

           if(ArrayManager.array_for_playing != null)
            if(SDcard.icurrentIndex != -1)
              playVideo(SDcard.icurrentIndex);
        }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: This usually happens when the media player's display is still set to the previous instance of the SurfaceHolder. The video is playing, but the frames are being sent to a Surface that is no longer on screen.

Answer (score -1):

You have to recreate your Media Player (`mPlayer`).

Just reuse your holder